# slabText and jQuery on a HTML boilerplate site

Tags: jquery, html, web, html5boilerplate

Total noob question: How do you "install"/setup etc slabText on a website? I'm using HTML Boilerplate and I see that there is already a link to jQuery but I'm not quite sure how to set up slabText so I can use it.

[slabText](https://github.com/freqdec/slabText)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a link to the slabText ".js" file (e.g. https://raw.github.com/freqdec/slabText/master/js/jquery.slabtext.js) AFTER the link to jQuery in your HTML page.

Looking at the Index page of Boilerplate, you could do something like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/freqdec/slabText/master/js/jquery.slabtext.js"></script>
```

**NOTE**: You should really download the slabText .js file and place it in the "js" directory like the other Boilerplate js files.

Comment: Another dumb question: how do I use slab text? I can read javascript a little (general programming knowledge) but I'm not quite sure how to use it in my site...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about slabtext. I would suggest reading the slabtext documentation or posting another specific question on SO.